# MKS Integrity: Getting content of archive (dropped member)

Tags: mks, mks-integrity

I know that I can use the CLI command `si viewrevision` to get the content of a versioned file. Downside is that this file must not be dropped.

Does anyone know a way (other than addfromarchive) to get the content when knowing the archive?

Comment: Just tried using `projectco` w/o luck. If the member is dropped, you need to know the last checkpoint when the member still existed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible

**si projectco** is documented as "checks out members of a project into working files".  If you drop the member from the project, it is no longer part of the project.

At first blush, **si viewrevision** doesn't explicitly state in the documentation that it requires a project, but if you try to run the command without a project (or a sandbox, which implies a project), you will be prompted for one.  Failing to provide one at the prompt exits the command with the message  'A value for "--project" is required.'  I tried doing this specifying a change package ID which the member was part of, and that still doesn't work.

Your **si addfromarchive** option is the only published way to do this.

**Disclosure**:  I am a PTC employee.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use add from archive?

You could also use a temporary server location (S:/Server/prj_tmp/project.pj)
as destination and the member will stay dropped in the original project.

(Ok, ok, someone could create a sandbox from S:/Server/prj_tmp/project.pj and generate new versions in the archive of the dropped member, ad/delete labels ...)

**There might be another possibility if your project has a checkpoint where the file was not yet dropped.**

Just create a build sandbox with the project revision of that checkpoint and then:

```
C:\BuildSandboxes\prjA\src> si viewrevision .....  :)
```

.

You might also use something like

```
C:\Sandboxes\prjA\src> si configuresubproject --subprojectRevision=1.2 --type=build project.pj
```

view your revision and then go back with

```
C:\Sandboxes\prjA\src> si configuresubproject --type=default project.pj
```

but this might affect user that are currently working on the project. (eg. they would not be able to check in while the subproject is configured as build)